# Python automating a wget script with login required

Tags: python, post, cookies

I need to automate a download process from a site which requires the following:

- send an HTTP POST request containing your username and password
- I should get a cookie *(probably containing a session ID)*
- send an HTTP GET request for the file, sending my cookie details in the HTTP headers

Using wget now, I must first login with a password *(open a session?)*:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O /dev/null --save-cookies auth.rda_ucar_edu --post-data=email=name@domain.edu&passwd=5555&action=login https://rda.ucar.edu/cgi-bin/login
```

then, I retrieve the files I need:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -N --load-cookies auth.rda_ucar_edu http://rda.ucar.edu/data/ds608.0/3HRLY/1979/NARRflx_197901_0916.tar
```

Is there a nice way to do this in Python?  I have tried many ways and have not gotten this to work.  The following python code seems to log me in correctly.  However, I believe I need to keep the session live while I download my data?

```
url = 'https://rda.ucar.edu/cgi-bin/login'
values = {'email': 'name@domain.edu', 'password': '5555', 'action': 'login'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
binary_data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib2.Request(url, binary_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

Have also tried this:

```
from requests import session
with session() as c:
    c.post(url, values)
    request = c.get('http://rda.ucar.edu/data/ds608.0/3HRLY/1979/NARRflx_197901_0108.tar')
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Why are you creating a `urllib2.Request` instance? You could have simply used `response = urllib2.urlopen(url, binary_data)`. Also, IIRC, you don't need to ascii-encode the output of `urlencode`. That *is*  the point of that function btw...

Answer (score 2):

You need to [save your cookies](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).

Easier to just use a 3rd party lib like [mechanize](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/) or [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) though