# Method to automate Arduino Yun WiFi Login to Captive Portal with python or other?

Tags: python, curl, arduino, wget, mechanize-python

What is the simplest path toward automating a WiFi login from an Arduino Yun (Yún) to a "Captive Portal" authenticated login method. I would like to stay in python, if that is the most appropriate.

So for I've considered:

- curl
- [wget](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#password-protected) ([Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091745/python-automating-a-wget-script-with-login-required))
- [mechanize](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/mechanize/)-
- [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html)

I would like the simplest, least-overhead method possible.

This is to run on an Arduino Yun upload some environmental data every once in a while.  But the publicly-accessible WiFi requires a login/password every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by talking to the Network Administrator and we have saved my Arduino as a privileged device. But I also want to know how to do that in order to prevent future problems and for Networks that I can't have privileged access.

By the way, I am using an UNO and python wouldn't solve my problem but the general idea can help me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use a headless browser like phantomjs, launched with nodejs to automate the navigation, input username/password